# how can I walk through a list of list of (x,y) in python

Tags: python

How can I walk through a list of list of `(x,y)` in python?

I have a data structure like this in python, which is a list of a list of a `(x,y)`

```
coords = [
      [[490, 185] , [490, 254], [490, 312] ],  # 0
      [[420, 135] , [492, 234], [491, 313], [325, 352] ],  # 1
]
```

I want to walk through the list and get `x, y` of each set:

```
# where count goes from 0 to 1
 a_set_coord[] = coords[count]
 for (tx, ty) in a_set_coord:
    print "tx = " + tx + " ty = " + ty
```

But I get error:

```
SyntaxError: ("no viable alternative at input ']'"
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Just FYI, the word you're looking for is [tuple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple)

Answer (score 3):

Remove the brackets after `a_set_coord`:

```
a_set_coord = coords[count]
```

Also, the `print` statement tries to concatenate strings and ints. Change it to:

```
print "tx = %d ty = %d" % (tx, ty)
```

Comment: or `print 'tx =', tx, 'ty =', ty`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to flatten your list of lists by one level, `itertools.chain` or `itertools.chain.from_iterable` could be very helpful:

```
>>> coords = [
...       [[490, 185] , [490, 254], [490, 312] ],  # 0
...       [[420, 135] , [492, 234], [491, 313], [325, 352] ],  # 1
... ]
>>> import itertools as it
>>> for x,y in it.chain.from_iterable(coords):
...     print ('tx = {0} ty = {1}'.format(x,y))
... 
tx = 490 ty = 185
tx = 490 ty = 254
tx = 490 ty = 312
tx = 420 ty = 135
tx = 492 ty = 234
tx = 491 ty = 313
tx = 325 ty = 352
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple `for` loop.

```
for i in coords:
   x = i[0]
   y = i[1]
   if len(i) == 3: z = i[2] # if there is a 'z' coordinate for a 3D graph.
   print(x, y, z)
```

This assumes that each list in `coords` is only of length 2 or 3. If it is different, this will not work. However, considering the lists are coordinates, it should be fine.